# BeautifulSoup4 showing me error when installing in PyCharm. Any viable alternatives?

Tags: python, web-crawler, pycharm

I'm trying to create a Spider by watching thenewboston tutorials, but when I try to install BeautifulSoup4 I get the following error:

[image: This is the error its showing]

Comment: Nobody will help you if you post screenshots of the code instead of the code.

Comment: You're installing the wrong package; you want `beautifulsoup4`, see https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You 've installed `BeautifulSoup3` which is not compatible with Python 3.

Use the following command to install `BeautifulSoup4`

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```